# Installing OpenJDK 7 didnt install javac

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk

I am very new to using the linux operating system and I'm currently using Ubuntu 13.10 coming off using windows for my whole life. I have been trying to get java development kit installed so I could create and compile java programs. However, when I installed the openJDK program from the ubuntu software center everything went fine and the program installed except it seems as though it didn't install javac to compile. When i open up terminal and type javac it comes up telling me where it can be found implying it wasn't installed. So I was wondering what I need to do in order to get javac to be installed so I could compile in programs such as eclipse.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `javac` (and other Java development tools) is available for `openjdk-7-jdk`.

Note that basic compiling within Eclipse *might* work without `javac` (but I still recommend having `javac`) because Eclipse uses its own compiler. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430592/installing-openjdk-7-didnt-install-javac/430622#comment558913_430599) answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a developer but you might need to have a look to Eclipse.

you can find details in below article and see if it suits you

- http://www.eclipse.org/home/newcomers.php

You can install it from Software Center; but for latest version; you will need to refer back to Eclipse [Website](http://www.eclipse.org/)

Comment: That's the IDE (to write code in), but you still need an external program (`javac`) to compile the code into Java bytecode.

Comment: @saiarcot895 Thanks for your clarificatio as I'm not a developer as I said before but willing to learn :) ,you might also need to have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler which say that Eclipse has its own compiler

Comment: Ah, interesting. That explains how Eclipse (and Netbeans) runs code with compile errors.